# Not able to add custom dimensions at different levels in measurement protocol google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I want to have some more dimensions so that the data for the user is more human readable.
I have set values such as
 { v: '1',
     tid: 'UA-XXXXX-1',
     cid: '55555',
     t: 'event',
     ec: 'GA',
     ea: 'GA_Recharge',
     el: 'Recharge_NameofUer',
     ev: '30' }

which provides me a three layered dimension but I want to add some more dimensions how could i achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are tracking events through the measurement protocol. Events have by default 3 dimensions:

- Event Category (ec)
- Event Action (ea)
- Event Label (el)

If you want to add more the first idea is to create customDimensions. You can have up to 20 custom dimensions (200 for GA360 clients).

You need to [setup them on the interface first](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827). You haven't given much information about your use case but I'll guess you want to set them with Hit Scope Level. Give each one a descriptive name on the UI and take note of their indexes.

Then you can use them in the [measurement protocol with the parameter cdX](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cd_), like this:

- Custom Dimension 1 (cd1)
- Custom Dimension 2(cd2)
- ...
- Custom Dimension 20 (cd20)

You can later create custom reports that mix these dimensions with the Event(Category|Action|Label) for easy reporting.

Comment: I created 3 event categories which has some event actions and some event labels can i further have more dimensions ? If so can you give me an example of that. @Eduardo

Answer (score 1):

Event category, event action and event label are all independent descriptors of a single hit.

To gain more 'levels' of a event, for example:

```
Event Category
Event Action
Event Label
Event Label 2
Event Label 3
Event Label 4
Event Label 5
```

You need to make use of custom dimensions. Hit level custom dimensions are at the same scope of the event, thus any additional information you send through with that hit will only be attached to that single event.

For example, if you want to capture the following event information:

Clicks > Link Clicks > Social Link Clicks > Facebook > Footer > Image Link

You would need to create 3 hit level custom dimensions. You could send it as follows:

```
{ v: '1', tid: 'UA-XXXXX-1', cid: '55555', t: 'event', ec: 'Clicks', ea: 'Link Clicks', 
el: 'Social Link Clicks', ev: '30',  cd1: 'Facebook', cd2: 'Footer', cd3: 'Image Link'}
```

Since all events are at the hit level, you can create and reserve extra custom dimensions as extra event levels and have no concern of the values over writing each other.

This means that you could send the following without concern:

Clicks > Signup Links > Social Options > Facebook > Body > CTA

```
{ v: '1', tid: 'UA-XXXXX-1', cid: '55555', t: 'event', ec: 'Clicks', ea: 'Signup Links', 
el: 'Social Options', ev: '30',  cd1: 'Facebook', cd2: 'Body', cd3: 'CTA'}
```

A report could be generated to see which type of links get clicked the most (Event Action), as well as what social platform is interacted with the most (CD1), or where users click the most (cd2).

Comment: I tried using the above input but I cannot see custom dimensions anywhere

Comment: Have you set up custom dimensions?

Comment: In the UI? yes i have given names cd1 ,cd2,cd3  and using api . I am using the below 

curl -X POST \
  https://www.google-analytics.com/collect \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: b383105e-66ab-bb41-84df-ec19cfc6f96b' \
  -d 'v=1&tid=UA-99373415-1&cid=1234567&t=event&ec=Clicks&ea=Link%20Clicks&el=Social%20Link%20Clicks&cd1=Telegram&cd2=Footer&cd3=Image%20Link'

Comment: And when you look at your event report and add in a secondary dimension for one of your CD's there is no data? Is your event there?